# cell remains in edit mode even after it loses focus in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in which I have two columns namely `Name` and `Group`.

I have used `EnterKeyTravarsal` Class, so that I can use <kbd>Enter</kbd> as <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Also Based on some Conditions I add a new row to DataGrid in the ViewModel using InputBindings.

But when a new row is added, I can see that the last cell that was focused just before adding a new row remains in the edit mode.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bbnJ2TnNDZGhsSGs/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample project that I have created to clearly explain my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your class `EnterKeyTraversal`

```
static void ue_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
    DataGrid dg = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(ue) as DataGrid;
    DataGridCell cell = FindVisualParent<DataGridCell>(ue);

    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //e.Handled = true;

        if (dg != null)
        {
            dg.CommitEdit();
        }

        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
        else
        {
            ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }

        if (dg != null)
        {
            dg.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will also need to handle the tab key in this case

Comment: Your solution worked as expected. But now I got another sample project with exactly the same problem where the above solution does not work. When I press enter on the last cell of any row a new row is added and the last cell of the previous row remains in edit mode. Can you check this sample : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bUUJlUU85T2RzZXc/edit?usp=sharing I have tried to apply your solution of dg.CommitEdit() just before line no. 314 in mainwindow.xaml

Comment: Also, I have noted that if I use DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn, then I dont get the above mentioned problem, I mean it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to download all your code but i'll try to help.

I remember i had a similar problem and i solved it using
either

```
this.grid.CommitEdit();
```

or

```
this.grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

in your case you might need yo use "DataGridEditingUnit.Cell"

I call the methods before inserting the new line, but I remember I had lots of problems to get them work and finally didn't get to understand them properly (they are working fine though), sorry :S

EDIT: Code por public DataGrid

```
public DataGrid MyGrid
{
  get 
  {
    return this.grid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Javi for trying to help me by answering this question. But how can I use `this.grid`? I am using MVVM. So, how do I refer to DataGrid in ViewModel?

Comment: Sorry, i have my DataGrid in code-behind. In your case in MainWindow.xaml just put x:Name="grid" and then try using this.grid in the xaml.cs. If you don't have the logic in the MainWIndow.xaml.cs just make there a public property that returns the DataGrid of the xaml

Comment: `just make there a public property that returns the DataGrid of the xaml.` Can you explain how to bind that new property to the dataGrid?

Comment: I have tried your code. But I am getting compilation error on this line : `return this.grid` saying that it cannot find the element `grid`. And it is obvious because my ViewModel will not find the elments in the View as it does not know the controls of View.

Comment: I'm looking at your MainWindow.xaml.cs I see that you have "private void DataGrid_CellGotFocus". have you try to capture the LostFocus of the cell? Is it fired?